# How can I pass make the text of a rich text box into a pre-defined variable in c#.net?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to make a rich text box display a variable that was declared earlier in the coding of this program, thanks to another user for telling me how to make a number randomly generated. The variable is just a piece of code that replaces an x with a random number. What I then want my program to do is put that number into a rich text box. The variables name is numStr14 and the rich text box's name is richResult. I've tried using
`richResult.Text = (numStr14)`
but it doesnt seem to work. I've also tried this with a normal textbox, but it doesnt work aswell. Any help would be appreciated. Feel free to ask questions. Thanks!

Edit: My error is "The name 'numStr14' does not exist in the current context.'"

Edit 2: The part that declares this variable:
`var code14 = "0xxxx0xxx000x0";`

`var numStr14 = Regex.Replace(code14, @"([^0-9.])", x => new Random().Next(1, 9).ToString());`

The code that provides this error:
`richResult.Text = (numStr14);`

Comment: Which error do you get? "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'"?

Comment: You're going to need to show more code, and tell us what error messages you are getting or be more explicit about *it doesn't seem to work*. Your description is like saying "I got in my car to go shopping and it didn't take me to the store".

Comment: @Igal My error is "The name 'numStr14' does not exist in the current context.'"

Comment: @Flydog57 which code would you like? The part that I define the variable in?

Comment: @Bizzie Edit your post and add all the parts of the code that contain this varible.

Comment: @Igal done. Those are the only places numStr14 is mentioned.

Comment: @Bizzie Try put all 3 lines in the same place and not separate them.
I didn't get any error after doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to put all three lines into the same area. Thank you very much Igal!